# search php object for empty value

Tags: php, oop, object

Looking for best way to accomplish below. I want to return TRUE if ANYTHING is empty in my user object, I don't care which one is empty. I think I've done this before with searching for empty values in an array but can't think of the best way to do this with objects.

I know I can loop thru the object and break once I find an empty value in the object, but checking first to see if there is a better way of doing this, thanks!

```
function is_it_empty($user)
{
 $is_it_empty = FALSE;
 if( isset($user->first_name) )
   $is_it_empty = TRUE;

 if( isset($user->last_name) )
   $is_it_empty = TRUE;

 return $is_it_empty;
}
```

also:

```
function name($user)
{
 foreach($user as $u):
   if( isset ($user->value) ): // or should it be isset?
      return true;
      break;
   endif;
 endforeach;

 return true;
}
```

Comment: what does $user object look like ?

Comment: $user->first_name, $user->last_name. I hope that answers it.

Comment: empty is used for arrays. For other values you should use isset.

Comment: @Maximus2012 That is incorrect. [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) checks if a variable "does not exist or if its value equals FALSE". `empty($var)` is equivalent to `!isset($var) || $var == false`. An array with zero elements is "empty" by this definition, and so is a string with zero characters, and the integer zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = new stdClass();
$user->firstName = 'Mark';
$user->lastName = 'Baker';
$user->sanity = NULL;

function is_it_empty($user) {
    foreach($user as $property) {
        if (empty($property)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(is_it_empty($user));
```

Comment: Note that this function will only work with `public` properties. See my answer to see into `private` and `protected` properties as per OP requirements. On the other hand i am very interested in how to inspect private/protected properties without using reflection!

Comment: Where's the OP's requirement that it should work for protected or private properties? I missed that

Comment: I probably misinterpreted `...I don't care which one is empty`. :-/ Anyways, he can choose whichever function gets the job done!

Answer (score 0):

u can use foreach. it's better than ur code.

```
        function is_it_empty($user)
        {
        foreach($user as $key=>$value)
        {
         if( empty($value) ){
           return = TRUE;
        }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case any one ever happens to care about encapsulation, this code might come in handly. The first function inspect public attributes only.

```
function is_prop_empty( $object ) {
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($object);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties();

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    try {
        $result = $prop->getvalue( $object );

        if( $result === null ) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
    }
}

return false;
}

var_dump( is_prop_empty($user) );
```

And with this second one, you can look into private and protected properties:

```
function is_prop_empty( $object ) {
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass($object);
    $props   = $reflect->getProperties();

    foreach ($props as $prop) {     
        $prop->setAccessible(true);
        $result = $prop->getvalue( $object );
        if( $result === null ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

#### EDIT

By empty, i assumed you meant `null` but you can modify the function(s) above to meet your requirements of "empty".

Answer (score 0):

I think having this generic function to check if a value exists would do the job

```
function is_empty($data) {
  if(empty($data) || !isset($data) || $data == false) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```